# Jquery HTML show then hide

Tags: ajax, jquery

i currently have the following AJAX response, which displays some HTML retrieved from the target page:

```
success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
$("#RoomAddResponse").html(data);
$("#RoomAdd")[0].reset();
```

How do i change it so that the HTML data shows for 5 seconds, then hides again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a timeout with a function that will empty `#RoomAddResponse`

```
success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $("#RoomAddResponse").html(data);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#RoomAddResponse").empty();
    }, 5000);
    $("#RoomAdd")[0].reset();
}
```